# JavaScript used to update price inside a form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a php file which is displaying price and quantities inside a form.

Comment: you will have to change name="quant" to name="quant[]" and name="price" to name="price[]" and then in your js- go through these arrays and update accordingly

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld so in my form change the id field to      name ="quant" id="quant[]" and name="price" id="price[]"
I dont get what you mean too much by go through the arrays in JS and update accordingly? As the array would depend on how many records are fetched from the db. Can you please show an example? I am not very good at JS and still learning:(

Comment: oh forgive me, I wasn't reading properly. Forget my comment :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld No probs:)

Comment: I know that you've accepted an answer, but take a look at mine as well .

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any question here and yet there are many answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't have more than one element with the same `id` in the resulting HTML. One way out is this:

```
$counter = 0;
while($queryresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    echo '<form method ="post" action="price.php">';
    echo '<input type="text" name ="quant" id="quant'.$counter.'" onblur="functionprice('.$counter.')" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name ="price" id="price'.$counter.'" onblur="functionprice('.$counter.')" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice'.$counter.'" readonly="true" />';
    echo "</form>";
    $counter++;
}//while
```

and then invoke this updated JavaScript function with the line number you want to change, like `functionprice(2);`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function functionprice(counter)
{
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quant"+counter).value);
    var quantity = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price"+counter).value);

    if (!(price == Number.NaN && quantity == Number.NaN))
        document.getElementById("unitprice"+counter).value = Number(price/quantity).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have not tested this but will defiantly test it tomorrow it looks right to me and I understand what is happening. Thanks very much :) I'll let you know how it goes tomorrow.

Comment: Just checked this now and it doesn't seem to work.. Like even the first row does not now update the price per unit. Is it because the function passes a arg and the the form we are not passing args? I tried this also 

onblur="functionprice($counter)";

any ideas?

Comment: fixed it mate.. it was because the function was not called.. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: updated thanks to Moch Daear. `onblur="functionprice('.$counter.')"`, the single ticks come from the php string and the `.` is string concatenation in php

Comment: Yes exactly what I did... after posing my comment of it not working lol .. Great stuff guys thanks a lot:D

Comment: Guys I have a small problem.. I was wondering if any of you know why this is. When the user clicks say an update button it updates the row saves it in the DB and a message is displayed the data was updated. However, ONLY WHEN the user refreshes the page, the update is seen else the row stays the same. So as soon as the page is refreshed the changed information is seen. Why may this be? Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all its bad to have same ID over multiple elements which is not W3C complaint. Probably this is the reason other form elements is not getting updated. You can either append the number on the `id` like `"quantity_1"` ,`"quantity_2"` so that you can have better control over you javascript code

And also if you want to treat it as a single row in database  , then use as per the comment above i.e name = 'price[]'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set `<form>` outside of the while-loop. Skip the id="", instead use class="" because id of element must be unique.

```
<?php
echo '<form method ="post" action="price.php">';

while($queryresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    $id = $queryresult['id']; //assumption is that id is an autoincremental integer
    echo '<input type="text" name ="quant[' . $id . ']" class="quant" onblur="functionprice(' . $id . ')" />'; //Make quant-array (dynamically)
    echo '<input type="text" name ="price[' . $id . ']" class="price" onblur="functionprice(' . $id . ')" />'; //Make price-array (dynamically)
    echo '<input type="text" name="unitprice[' . $id . ']" id="unitprice" readonly="true" />';
}//while

echo "</form>"

?>//close php tag
?>
```

Then do something like this (I hope you get the concept)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function functionprice(id)
{
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById ("quant[" + id + "]").value); //Get value of element in quant-array
    var quantity = parseFloat(document.getElementById ("price[" + id + "]").value); //Get value of element in price-array

    if (!(price == Number.NaN && quantity == Number.NaN))
        document.getElementById ("unitprice[" + id + "]").value = Number(price/quantity).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

When making code like this (above), you could use the built array when retrieving values server-side (very easily). The only downside with this - as I see it - is that if you have big resultsets (like >100.000 rows) - arrays could "eat up" memory on the server.

**Example:**
If you put a submit-button after the while-loop and inside the `<form>` like this:
    ';

```
while($queryresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    $id = $queryresult['id']; //assumption is that id is an autoincremental integer
    echo '<input type="text" name ="quant[' . $id . ']" class="quant" onblur="functionprice(' . $id . ')" />'; //Make quant-array (dynamically)
    echo '<input type="text" name ="price[' . $id . ']" class="price" onblur="functionprice(' . $id . ')" />'; //Make price-array (dynamically)
    echo '<input type="text" name="unitprice[' . $id . ']" id="unitprice" readonly="true" />';
}//while

echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Skicka\" />";
echo "</form>"

?>//close php tag
?>
```

then in price.php (after a submit) you get values by doing something like this: (validation should be done also of course so you get the expected values/arrays you want)

```
<?php
$quantArr = $_POST['quant'];
$priceArr = $_POST['price'];

//echo out a certain row from db (where id = 27)
echo 'quantity: ' . $quantArr[27];
echo 'price: ' . $pricearr[27];
?>
```

Comment: Hey buddy. Thanks very much for this. It works and I understand totally what you are doing. The reason why I needed form inside the while loop is beacuse I am submitting data for each row. like row1-option to subnit... row2 -- option to submit (button),.. Hence i need a form each time a row is outputted. if that makes sense?
but thanks for the JS idea.. Like I said still a  newbie but this works so thanks:)

Comment: @user2288273 - you're welcome! I've added an example so you actually could benfiit from the fact that arrays have been created. (And you won't have to add several forms just for adding rows)

Comment: Yes indeed so that would also work. Thanks mate I shall make this modification as what you say is very valid. Once again thanks. PS. I wont have that many records so memory it should be okay. :) Thank you.

Comment: hey mate can you pelase help me on my other small issue I had.. I have posted it in the first answer here it is:
When the user clicks say an update button it updates the row saves it in the DB and a message is displayed the data was updated. However, ONLY WHEN the user refreshes the page, the update is seen else the row stays the same. So as soon as the page is refreshed the changed information is seen. Why may this be? Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Glad to help. About your other issue - i really don't understand what you're asking. Maybe you could make a new question about it (included with code) ?

Comment: What I mean to ask is. The user clicks submit the query is successful I echo "your click was registered and the data was sent to the client"
Now the row stays the same on the webpage.. when the user clicks refresh on there browser only then is the row they just clicked on updated.. Does that make sense? so the echo and the query do run when clicked but user has to refresh the page to see the result to the data.. Any ideas or shall i submit a question. (I dont want to annoy users by asking stupid questions you see lol...)

Comment: @user2288273 - submit a question. It's hard to tell what's going on without any code. Try to explain your problem and what you've tried and people won't get annoyed.

Comment: Okay I shall do that first thing tomorrow. Thanks buddy :)